# How to put ajax-loader while the page is loading in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Help me guys to make page loader while the page is loading. I'm doing some paypal payment system. As I watch some pages, when the page is directing to paypal page, they put some loader(ajax loader) while the page is processing to redirect to "Paypal gateway". I'm also planning to put some Ajax loader in my other page while they're loading. So please help me guys. Here is my code.

```
<?php
            $current_url = base64_encode($url='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

                if(isset($_POST['checkoutnow'])){
                    header('Location: checkout_now1.php');
                }
                if(isset($_SESSION["products"])){
                    $total = 0;
                    echo '<ol>';
                    echo '<form action="paypal-express-checkout/process.php" method="POST">';
                    $cart_items = 0;

                        foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm)
    {
       $product_code = $cart_itm["code"];
       $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT product_name,product_desc, price FROM products WHERE product_code='$product_code' LIMIT 1");
       $obj = $results->fetch_object();

        echo '<li class="cart-itm">';
        echo '<span class="remove-itm"><a href="cart_update.php?removep='.$cart_itm["code"].'&return_url='.$current_url.'">&times;</a></span>';
        echo '<div class="p-price">'.$currency.$obj->price.'</div>';
        echo '<div class="product-info">';
        echo '<h3>'.$obj->product_name.' (Code :'.$product_code.')</h3> ';
        echo '<div class="p-qty">Qty : '.$cart_itm["qty"].'</div>';
        echo '<div>'.$obj->product_desc.'</div>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</li>';
        $subtotal = ($cart_itm["price"]*$cart_itm["qty"]);
        $total = ($total + $subtotal);

        echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_name['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$obj->product_name.'" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_code['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$product_code.'" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_desc['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$obj->product_desc.'" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_qty['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$cart_itm["qty"].'" />';
        $cart_items ++;

                        }
                    echo '</ol>';
                    echo '<strong>Total: '.$currency.$total.'</strong><br />';

                    echo '<center>
                            <div id="check_out">
                                <a href="checkout_now1.php"><button>Check Out with US</button></a><br />OR<br />
                                <div class="paypal-button"><input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckoutsm.gif"></div>
                            </center>
                            </div>';
                                echo '</form>';
                }else{
                    echo 'Your Cart is Empty<br />Go to <a href="index.php">Home</a> And Order';

                }

        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do so, you can use javascript method "`setInterval()`" to put a time between two process or more. I didn't get where is you condition to put this delay, but I link you my code and hope it helps :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8" />
        <title> title-page </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
            function loading() {
                var miliSecTime = 1000; // 1 sec time between each process for example
                document.getElementById("waitDiv").InnerHtml = "<img src = 'wait.gif' />";
                var timer = setInterval(function () {
                        // BEGIN : Your process

                        // END : Your process

                        // Condition to abort the process
                        // Likely when you want to stop
                        // the waiting view
                        if (leftLoading_condition) {
                            clearInterval(timer);
                            document.getElementById("waitDiv").innerHTML = ""; // Hidding the wait view
                        }
                    },
                    miliSecTime
                );
            }
        </script>
        <!-- This is where you want to show you wait gif -->
        <div id = "waitDiv">

        </div>
        <input type = "button" onClick = "loading()" />
    </body>
</html>
```

The "`setInterval()`" function takes two parameters : the first is you function, the second is the delay you want to put between each tick. So you make a proces into the function method, and the trick is to put a left tick event condition, with the call of the method "clearInterval" which will stop the tick.

So here is the work of this code :

The function "loading" is called by clicking on the button. The method launch the process which is included in the "`function () {}`" code. Before launching this process, we show the wait gif, which can be a loading gif or whatever. Then, the process run in loop until the left tick condition (the if() call). If we have reach the end of the process, the timer is aborted by clearing the interval parameters (by calling "`clearInterval()`" method).

Comment: Thank bro. Let me try this bro. I'll contact you what happen. I hope it will load. :)

Comment: If you have a single process, and you just want to set a delay between the process and the result, just take a look at the "setTimeout()" javascript function which is similar to the one I used in this example. Hope you get what you want !

Comment: Bro. None of your codes made a changes. :( What do you think is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("../config.php");
include_once("paypal.class.php");

$paypalmode = ($PayPalMode=='sandbox') ? '.sandbox' : '';

if($_POST) //Post Data received from product list page.
{
//Other important variables like tax, shipping cost
$TotalTaxAmount     = 2.58;  //Sum of tax for all items in this order. 
$HandalingCost      = 2.00;  //Handling cost for this order.
$InsuranceCost      = 1.00;  //shipping insurance cost for this order.
$ShippinDiscount    = -3.00; //Shipping discount for this order. Specify this as negative number.
$ShippinCost        = 3.00; //Although you may change the value later, try to pass in a shipping amount that is reasonably accurate.

//we need 4 variables from product page Item Name, Item Price, Item Number and Item Quantity.
//Please Note : People can manipulate hidden field amounts in form,
//In practical world you must fetch actual price from database using item id. 
//eg : $ItemPrice = $mysqli->query("SELECT item_price FROM products WHERE id = Product_Number");
$paypal_data ='';
$ItemTotalPrice = 0;

foreach($_POST['item_name'] as $key=>$itmname)
{
    $product_code   = filter_var($_POST['item_code'][$key], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 

    $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT product_name, product_desc, price FROM products WHERE product_code='$product_code' LIMIT 1");
    $obj = $results->fetch_object();

    $paypal_data .= '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME'.$key.'='.urlencode($obj->product_name);
    $paypal_data .= '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER'.$key.'='.urlencode($_POST['item_code'][$key]);
    $paypal_data .= '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'.$key.'='.urlencode($obj->price);      
    $paypal_data .= '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY'.$key.'='. urlencode($_POST['item_qty'][$key]);

    // item price X quantity
    $subtotal = ($obj->price*$_POST['item_qty'][$key]);

    //total price
    $ItemTotalPrice = $ItemTotalPrice + $subtotal;

    //create items for session
    $paypal_product['items'][] = array('itm_name'=>$obj->product_name,
                                        'itm_price'=>$obj->price,
                                        'itm_code'=>$_POST['item_code'][$key], 
                                        'itm_qty'=>$_POST['item_qty'][$key]
                                        );
}

//Grand total including all tax, insurance, shipping cost and discount
$GrandTotal = ($ItemTotalPrice + $TotalTaxAmount + $HandalingCost + $InsuranceCost + $ShippinCost + $ShippinDiscount);


$paypal_product['assets'] = array('tax_total'=>$TotalTaxAmount, 
                            'handaling_cost'=>$HandalingCost, 
                            'insurance_cost'=>$InsuranceCost,
                            'shippin_discount'=>$ShippinDiscount,
                            'shippin_cost'=>$ShippinCost,
                            'grand_total'=>$GrandTotal);

//create session array for later use
$_SESSION["paypal_products"] = $paypal_product;

//Parameters for SetExpressCheckout, which will be sent to PayPal
$padata =   '&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout'.
            '&RETURNURL='.urlencode($PayPalReturnURL ).
            '&CANCELURL='.urlencode($PayPalCancelURL).
            '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION='.urlencode("SALE").
            $paypal_data.               
            '&NOSHIPPING=0'. //set 1 to hide buyer's shipping address, in-case products that does not require shipping
            '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT='.urlencode($ItemTotalPrice).
            '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT='.urlencode($TotalTaxAmount).
            '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT='.urlencode($ShippinCost).
            '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT='.urlencode($HandalingCost).
            '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT='.urlencode($ShippinDiscount).
            '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT='.urlencode($InsuranceCost).
            '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT='.urlencode($GrandTotal).
            '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE='.urlencode($PayPalCurrencyCode).
            '&LOCALECODE=GB'. //PayPal pages to match the language on your website.
            '&LOGOIMG='. //site logo
            '&CARTBORDERCOLOR=FFFFFF'. //border color of cart
            '&ALLOWNOTE=1';

    //We need to execute the "SetExpressCheckOut" method to obtain paypal token
    $paypal= new MyPayPal();
    $httpParsedResponseAr = $paypal->PPHttpPost('SetExpressCheckout', $padata, $PayPalApiUsername, $PayPalApiPassword, $PayPalApiSignature, $PayPalMode);

    //Respond according to message we receive from Paypal
    if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]))
    {
            //Redirect user to PayPal store with Token received.
            $paypalurl ='https://www'.$paypalmode.'.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token='.$httpParsedResponseAr["TOKEN"].'';
            header('Location: '.$paypalurl);
    }
    else
    {
        //Show error message
        echo '<div style="color:red"><b>Error : </b>'.urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]).'</div>';
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($httpParsedResponseAr);
        echo '</pre>';
    }

}

//Paypal redirects back to this page using ReturnURL, We should receive TOKEN and Payer ID
if(isset($_GET["token"]) && isset($_GET["PayerID"]))
{
//we will be using these two variables to execute the "DoExpressCheckoutPayment"
//Note: we haven't received any payment yet.

$token = $_GET["token"];
$payer_id = $_GET["PayerID"];

//get session variables
$paypal_product = $_SESSION["paypal_products"];
$paypal_data = '';
$ItemTotalPrice = 0;

foreach($paypal_product['items'] as $key=>$p_item)
{       
    $paypal_data .= '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY'.$key.'='. urlencode($p_item['itm_qty']);
    $paypal_data .= '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'.$key.'='.urlencode($p_item['itm_price']);
    $paypal_data .= '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME'.$key.'='.urlencode($p_item['itm_name']);
    $paypal_data .= '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER'.$key.'='.urlencode($p_item['itm_code']);

    // item price X quantity
    $subtotal = ($p_item['itm_price']*$p_item['itm_qty']);

    //total price
    $ItemTotalPrice = ($ItemTotalPrice + $subtotal);
}

$padata =   '&TOKEN='.urlencode($token).
            '&PAYERID='.urlencode($payer_id).
            '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION='.urlencode("SALE").
            $paypal_data.
            '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT='.urlencode($ItemTotalPrice).
            '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT='.urlencode($paypal_product['assets']['tax_total']).
            '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT='.urlencode($paypal_product['assets']['shippin_cost']).
            '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT='.urlencode($paypal_product['assets']['handaling_cost']).
            '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT='.urlencode($paypal_product['assets']['shippin_discount']).
            '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT='.urlencode($paypal_product['assets']['insurance_cost']).
            '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT='.urlencode($paypal_product['assets']['grand_total']).
            '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE='.urlencode($PayPalCurrencyCode);

//We need to execute the "DoExpressCheckoutPayment" at this point to Receive payment from user.
$paypal= new MyPayPal();
$httpParsedResponseAr = $paypal->PPHttpPost('DoExpressCheckoutPayment', $padata, $PayPalApiUsername, $PayPalApiPassword, $PayPalApiSignature, $PayPalMode);

//Check if everything went ok..
if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])) 
{

        echo '<h2>Success</h2>';
        echo 'Your Transaction ID : '.urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID"]);

            /*
            //Sometimes Payment are kept pending even when transaction is complete. 
            //hence we need to notify user about it and ask him manually approve the transiction
            */

            if('Completed' == $httpParsedResponseAr["PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS"])
            {
                echo '<div style="color:green">Payment Received! Your product will be sent to you very soon!</div>';
            }
            elseif('Pending' == $httpParsedResponseAr["PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS"])
            {
                echo '<div style="color:red">Transaction Complete, but payment is still pending! '.
                'You need to manually authorize this payment in your <a target="_new" href="http://www.paypal.com">Paypal Account</a></div>';
            }

            // we can retrive transection details using either GetTransactionDetails or GetExpressCheckoutDetails
            // GetTransactionDetails requires a Transaction ID, and GetExpressCheckoutDetails requires Token returned by SetExpressCheckOut
            $padata =   '&TOKEN='.urlencode($token);
            $paypal= new MyPayPal();
            $httpParsedResponseAr = $paypal->PPHttpPost('GetExpressCheckoutDetails', $padata, $PayPalApiUsername, $PayPalApiPassword, $PayPalApiSignature, $PayPalMode);

            if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])) 
            {

                echo '<br /><b>Stuff to store in database :</b><br />';

                echo '<pre>';
                /*
                #### SAVE BUYER INFORMATION IN DATABASE ###
                //see (http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/basic-php-mysqli-usage) for mysqli usage
                //use urldecode() to decode url encoded strings.

                $buyerName = urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["FIRSTNAME"]).' '.urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["LASTNAME"]);
                $buyerEmail = urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["EMAIL"]);

                //Open a new connection to the MySQL server
                $mysqli = new mysqli('host','username','password','database_name');

                //Output any connection error
                if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
                    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
                }       

                $insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO BuyerTable 
                (BuyerName,BuyerEmail,TransactionID,ItemName,ItemNumber, ItemAmount,ItemQTY)
                VALUES ('$buyerName','$buyerEmail','$transactionID','$ItemName',$ItemNumber, $ItemTotalPrice,$ItemQTY)");

                if($insert_row){
                    print 'Success! ID of last inserted record is : ' .$mysqli->insert_id .'<br />'; 
                }else{
                    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
                }

                */

                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($httpParsedResponseAr);
                echo '</pre>';
            } else  {
                echo '<div style="color:red"><b>GetTransactionDetails failed:</b>'.urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]).'</div>';
                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($httpParsedResponseAr);
                echo '</pre>';

            }

}else{
        echo '<div style="color:red"><b>Error : </b>'.urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]).'</div>';
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($httpParsedResponseAr);
        echo '</pre>';
}
}
?>
```